# how do you do a type casting in one line in c?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, type-punning

how do you do a type casting in one line in c?

```c
unsigned char num[4]={0,2}; //512 little endian
unsigned int * ptr = num;

printf("%u\n", *ptr); // 512

//trying to do the same underneath in one line but it dosen't work    
printf("%u\n", (unsigned int *)num); //
```

Comment: You type pun num to an unsigned int pointer, you will need to dereference it by prefixing the punning with a *. ```*(unsigned int *)num```

Comment: This is not type casting, but type punning, which is a dangerous game. If your `num` is not aligned as `int` on a system that requires alignment, then this access will produce alignment error.

Comment: @jh316 aah you are great, thank you i should accept you comment as an answer

Comment: @EugeneSh. i see but it's much shorter to type it as in one line , but i will definitely keep that in mind , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same as

```
unsigned int * ptr = num; printf("%u\n", *ptr); // !! nonportable, nonsafe (UB-invoking)
```

in one line would be

```
printf("%u\n", *(unsigned int *)num); // !! nonportable, nonsafe (UB-invoking)
```

However both versions are nonportable and unsafe. They invoke undefined behavior by violating the strict aliasing rule and possibly by creating a pointer that's not suitably aligned.

You can do it safely with memcpy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    unsigned char num[4]={0,2}; //512 little endian

    #if 0
    //the unsafe versions
    unsigned int * ptr = num; printf("%u\n", *ptr);
    printf("%u\n", *(unsigned int *)num);
    #endif

    //the safe version using a compound literal as an anonymous temporary;
    //utilizes how memcpy returns the destination address
    printf("%u\n",*(unsigned*){memcpy(&(unsigned){0},&num,sizeof(num))});

}
```

Comment: `memcpy` didn't think of that ..  i guess i will stick with `memcpy` rather than `printf("%u\n",*(unsigned*){memcpy(&(unsigned){0},&num,sizeof(num))});
` can be quite hard to read,
 great answer .. 

Comment: as such `unsigned int resultNum;` `memcpy(&resultNum,num,4);`

Comment: @dinolin Yeah, I'd also prefer the named-variable version. The question title specifically asked for one line (commonly understood as one statement), though, so that's what I answered with :).

Comment: you are right it was to be in one line :P.. thanks for such a great answer

Comment: `unsigned char num[sizeof (unsigned)]` avoids the magic number 4.